# JMS Message Persistence in Wildfly 8.0 server

Tags: java, jboss7.x, message, wildfly, persistent-storage

How can i achieve message Persistence in the case of JMS in Wildfly server or Jboss 7.1.1 final?

Can i persist the messsgaes in database using any Wildfly provided services?

Any help would be appreciated, I am working on JBoss 5 to Wildlfy Migration where i have this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HornetQ, the JMS implementation bundled with WildFly, uses persistent storage by default. This is true at least for 8.2.0.Final, I didn't check earlier releases.

"Persistent" and "database" are not synonymous. HornetQ uses the filesystem for persistence, but that shouldn't really make a difference to your application.

Comment: thanks for the reply..But in Jboss 5.1.0 We are persisting the messages into the database using the "JDBCPersistenceManagerService","MessagingPostOfficeService","JDBCJMSUserManagerService" services of Jboss 5.  So can we achieve  that in the case of Wildfly.

Comment: You can't. And you didn't explain why you think you need to. HornetQ does not work with relational databases for performance reasons: see the [HornetQ manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/index.html#persistence).

Comment: The reason is ,in our project we enqueue a log file from one point to another.In this case ,we are using that feature from Jboss 5 to save the log file in the database before it is delivered to the subscriber.